# How to update the dynamic island view after a certain interval of time in App kill state.?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16, activitykit

I want to start the dynamic island live activity for count down timer with event title.
Like christmas in 05 days.

I am trying to update it with the help of timer in extension, but not able to update the view.

```
 Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [self] time in
            
           
                 if minute < 1 {
                     updateActivity(dynamicIslandType: dynamicIslandType, minute: 0)
                     time.invalidate()
                }
```

I have tried this code in widget extension to update the view, but not able to get any update of the view.

Comment: You can't have `Timer`s in a widget extension, updates need to come from the main app. You can use background tasks to try and keep it updated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities for something as long as days